# NLog, custom LogLevels

Tags: nlog

In the config file config.json I have this entry

```
 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "MyEntry": "Critical"
    }
  }
```

I'm lacking the terminology to do a proper search here.

I've added an extra entry, "MyEntry". What is that? Is it a category? What would I need to do to get it to do something?

What I'm actually trying to do is just make a reference sandbox project so that I can play with the various settings of nlog

Comment: Why kind of app are you playing with? Maybe try out the NLog Wiki Examples: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application or https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-5

Comment: Asp.Net Core. I have seen the example that you've supplied, however I just can't find in the documentation what I would need to do to get that 'MyEntry' section to have an effect. i.e. I assumed it would be something like logger.Log("MyEntry", ..., . 
What does the "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" mean here?

Comment: `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime` is the Logger-category, or in the NLog world it is called the Logger-Name. When creating an instance of ILogger, then it can be given a name, and you can do filtering based on the Logger-name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted now thanks to the help in the comments

Here's 2 examples, one using a class name, and one using a random name.

The log file

```
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Critical",
        "Microsoft": "Critical",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Critical",
        "NLogUsing.Controllers.TempController": "Critical",
        "SomeRandomNameLogger": "Information"
    }
  },
```

And some code that uses it

```
namespace NLogUsing.Controllers
{
   [Route("/Temp")]
    public class TempController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TempController> classLogger;
        private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger namedLogger = null;

        public TempController(ILogger<TempController> logger, ILoggerFactory logFactory)
        {
            classLogger = logger;
            namedLogger = logFactory.CreateLogger("SomeRandomNameLogger");
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("Bob")]
        public async Task<string> Bob()
        {
            classLogger.LogDebug(1, "ClassName Debug");
            classLogger.LogInformation(1, "ClassName Info");
            classLogger.LogTrace(1, "ClassName trace");
            classLogger.LogWarning(1, "ClassName warning");
            classLogger.LogCritical(1, "ClassName critical");
            classLogger.LogError(1, "ClassName error");

            namedLogger.LogDebug(1, "Named Debug");
            namedLogger.LogInformation(1, "Named Info");
            namedLogger.LogTrace(1, "Named trace");
            namedLogger.LogWarning(1, "Named warning");
            namedLogger.LogCritical(1, "Named critical");
            namedLogger.LogError(1, "Named error");


            return await Task.FromResult<string>("Bob");
        }
```